# How to repeat just a certain part of the function in python if a condition is met?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am writing a web scraping script that does different things depending on what was scrapped from the website.

So far everything works. But sometimes the website loads a bit slower randomly and I would get the text "Loading" in my result.

If that happens, I want it to wait a few seconds and scrap again, then use the new results to do things under the `else:` part of the function.

Problem is I have no idea how to make it work. I Googled a bit and it seems using while loop is the solution. But I cannot figure out how to implement it in my code (because the action I want it to repeat is inside the very same function?). Or is there a better way to do it?

Here is my code:

```
def Webscraping(page_url):
    #Webscraping the URL from user input

def MakeTableFromData(input):
    #input some data, print out a table made from data

def Work(page_url):
    scrapped_text = Webscraping(page_url)
    scrapped_string= ''.join(scrapped_text)
    newlistings1 = scrapped_string.split('\n')
#turn the scrapped text into a list

    with open(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\NEW_LISTINGS1.json', 'w',encoding='UTF-8') as f:
      json.dump(newlistings1, f, ensure_ascii = False)

    if "Sorry but you need to complete the captcha test to continue" in newlistings1:
        print("Captcha Test")
        exit()
    
    elif "No match" in newlistings1:
        print("No listing currently")

    elif "Loading" in newlistings1:
        time.sleep(3)
    #I don't know how to write this part
    #Wait a bit and repeat the whole process of web scraping, then do everthing underneath else:
    
    else:    
        # Do things with data

            MakeTableFromData(newlistings1)
        
            with open(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\old_listing1.json', 'w',encoding='UTF-8') as f:
              json.dump(newest1, f, ensure_ascii = False)
            print("Updated old_listing1.json")

page_url = input("Enter the link.")
Work(page_url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to do this **recursively**, in order to make sure that the 'scrapping' logic is always the same. To do so, you'd just have to call again your function `Work` under the condition :

```
 elif "Loading" in newlistings1:
        time.sleep(3)
        Work(page_url)
```

However, there is an associated risk : what if the webpage is broken and you always end in up in "Loading" case ? Then you'd have an infinite loop. To solve this there are many different ways. You could add a parameter `count = 0` to the function work: `def Work(page_url, count=0)`. Then, the first part of the body should be checking that `count`is under a threshold (say, 3) and if not `return false` (to break the infinite call loop). Then, you condition could call the function with `Work(page_url, count + 1)`.

```py
def Work(page_url, count=0):
    if count > 3:
      return 
    # do your things
    elif "Loading" in newlistings1:
        time.sleep(3)
        Work(page_url, count+1)
```

This is just one way and probably not the best one, but it would work fine.

Comment: I didn't know you could call the function again under the same function!Thank you

Comment: Yes, it is a common technique called **recursive functions**  (I am sure you'll find good intro to recursive programming online). It provides elegant solutions to some cases (like this one!) but comes at a risk: the recursion must be guaranteed to be stopped at some point, else you'll have an infinite call of the function.